# SQL: Calculate (and populate?) difference between ordered results

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using MariaDB (according my limited conception, a drop-in replacement for MySQL) to back a little elections application.

One of the things I store with a candidate is a "leadingmargin" - i.e., how much their plurality is. If candidate A wins 6 votes, candidate B wins 12, and candidate C wins 7, the values are then 0, 5, 0.

But now I have a large new data set where I know the ridings and the votes, but have nothing for "leadingmargin". There are hundreds of candidates, so I need to calculate this. This is what I mean to do in English:

1. Sort everybody by riding.
2. Then sort by votes.
3. Subtract (first-ranked-candidate's votes - second-ranked-candidate's votes) and store the result in the "leading margin" column of the first-ranked.
4. Everybody else gets a 0. Or just leave it NULL.

Here's an example of a completed table to show what I'm going for. The only difference between it and the real data is that I don't have the "leadingmargin"s calculated yet.

```
MariaDB [databasename]> SELECT * FROM `demo_candidates` ORDER BY `riding` ASC , `votes` DESC;
+--------+-----------+-----------+---------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+
| id     | riding    | lname     | fname   | party | votes | leadingmargin | percent |
+--------+-----------+-----------+---------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+
|      1 |         1 | Redford   | Richard |     1 |    92 |            50 |   57.14 |
|      4 |         1 | Pelford   | Paul    |     4 |    42 |             0 |   26.09 |
|      3 |         1 | Yeltmate  | Yoris   |     3 |    16 |             0 |    9.94 |
|      2 |         1 | Gint      | Ginny   |     2 |    11 |             0 |    6.83 |
|      6 |         2 | Gelford   | Gippy   |     2 |    99 |            16 |   44.59 |
|      5 |         2 | Roberts   | Roy     |     1 |    83 |             0 |   37.39 |
|      8 |         2 | Peg       | Porkay  |     4 |    28 |             0 |   12.61 |
|      7 |         2 | Yavin     | Yordy   |     3 |    12 |             0 |    5.41 |
etc..
+--------+-----------+-----------+---------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+
20 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This is a job for cursors or for an application that does post-processing on the data.  Can you DO it in pure SQL?  Almost definitely.  Will it be pretty and/or performant?  Almost definitely not.  Also, if you ever update a row to change the value of the votes column for a given row, the leadingmargin column will no longer be accurate and will, itself, have to be updated again.  In other words, leadingmargin is likely a value you should just calculate at runtime, when you use the value for display (for example, in a viewmodel class).

Comment: That's a very good point - it's not a problem for me, because the results are "in the can" and won't be changing (unless there's a wacky court ruling or something). But yeah, I can probably do this in PHP much more easily. I'll do that in the future or if this becomes a tumbleweed.

Comment: If mySQL supports them, bringing your subset of data into a table variable (in-memory table basically) or even a temp table could significantly boost performance if that's a concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query only sets the leading margin for the winners. If you set the DEFAULT value for leadingmargin to 0, or run another query to set those to 0, you'll be good:

```
UPDATE demo_candidates t1
LEFT JOIN demo_candidates t2
  ON t2.riding = t1.riding
  AND t2.votes > t1.votes
JOIN demo_candidates t3
  ON t3.riding = t1.riding
  AND t3.votes < t1.votes
LEFT JOIN demo_candidates t4
  ON t4.riding = t3.riding
  AND t4.id <> t1.id
  AND t4.votes > t3.votes
SET t1.leadingmargin = t1.votes - t3.votes
WHERE t2.id IS NULL AND t4.id IS NULL
```

If there is a tie for winner or there is only one candidate, the leadingmargin won't be set.

**UPDATE:**

This one sets the `0`'s too:

```
UPDATE demo_candidates t1
LEFT JOIN demo_candidates t2
  ON t2.riding = t1.riding
  AND t2.votes > t1.votes
LEFT JOIN demo_candidates t3
  ON t3.riding = t1.riding
  AND t3.votes < t1.votes
LEFT JOIN demo_candidates t4
  ON t4.riding = t3.riding
  AND t4.id <> t1.id
  AND t4.votes > t3.votes
SET t1.leadingmargin = IF(t2.id IS NULL AND t4.id IS NULL, t1.votes - t3.votes, 0)
```

Comment: Ties and acclamation are so rare in major elections that it's simpler to just handle those cases manually. Well, unless I have an app that handles thousands of elections. But this is mostly just an academic exercise for myself.

Does this work if there are more than four candidates? I had two with 5 candidates and it happened to work anyway.

Comment: @WillMatheson, see my update. Yes, it will work for any number of candidates (> 1).